# i am getting error "file contains error" in code.(only in this file) what to do

Tags: error-handling, syntax, virus

cd "c:\Users\komal\DSA" ; if ($?) { gcc bisection.c -o bisection } ; if ($?) { .\bisection }
Program 'bisection.exe' failed to run: Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted softwareAt
line:1 char:81

- ...  ; if ($?) { gcc bisection.c -o bisection } ; if ($?) { .\bisection }
- ```
                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~.
  ```

At line:1 char:81

- ...  ; if ($?) { gcc bisection.c -o bisection } ; if ($?) { .\bisection }
- ```
                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

i tried to implement code in new file but it's not working .
**what to do?**